# Bounded sets in l2

Tags: functional-analysis

Are sets $A,B,C$ bounded in $l_2$ (field - $\mathbb{C}$)?
$$A = \left\{ \left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_2: \; x_1 = x_2 \right\}$$
$$B = \left\{ \left( x_n \right)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \in l_2 : \; \left( x_n \right)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \in l_1 \right\}$$
$$C = \left\{ \left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_2: \; x_n  \neq 0 ;\ \mbox{for finitely many } n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

For $A$,
 $$\color{red}{(}x_n\color{red}{)} =\color{red}{\left(\right.} \sqrt{2+n^2}\color{red}{\left.\right)}$$
$$\sup \left\{ \| x \| : \;  x \in A \right\}  \ge \sup \left\{\sqrt{2+n^2} : \;  n \in  \mathbb{N} \right\}
 \rightarrow  \infty$$ when $n \to \infty$.

For $B$, 
 $$\color{red}{(}x_n\color{red}{)} = \left(\underbrace{ \frac{2^n}{n},  \frac{2^n}{n}, \ldots \frac{2^n}{n} }_{n \; } , 0,0 \ldots   \right) \in B$$ 
$$\| x_n \| =\sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{n^2}}= \sqrt{\frac{4^n}{n} }  < \infty$$
$$\sup \left\{ \| x \| : \;  x \in B \right\}  \ge \sup \left\{\sqrt{\frac{4^n}{n}}  : \;  n \in  \mathbb{N} \right\} \rightarrow  \infty$$ when $n \to \infty$.

For $C$,

$$\color{red}{(}x_n\color{red}{)} = \left(\underbrace{ \frac{2^n}{n},  \frac{2^n}{n}, \ldots \frac{2^n}{n} }_{n \; } ,0.0,  \ldots   \right) \in C$$ 
 $$\| x_n \| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{n^2}}= \sqrt{\frac{4^n}{n} }  < \infty$$
$$\sup \left\{ \| x \| : \;  x \in C \right\}  \ge \sup \left\{ \sqrt{\frac{4^n}{n} } : \;  n \in  \mathbb{N} \right\} \rightarrow  \infty$$ when $n \to \infty$.

Correct?

Comment: You need a lot more explanation.  Which spaces each of the things you define belong to.  Words to explain what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, I think that is fine. By the way, there are many examples that work for the three sets simultaneously. For example, $(x_n)=(0,0,n,0,...)$.